# How to display push notification in apple watch?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, apple-watch

I am developing an iphone app using Appcelerator, In which I registered for push notification, so when I receive a push notification and device is locked I want to show that in paired apple watch. So my question is Do I need to include any apple watch extension to my project or by default it will display in apple watch?
I don't have an apple watch device so I cant test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notifications will show up on the Apple Watch automatically:

If your iOS app supports local or remote notifications, Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times.

iOS it self decide to pass the notification to Apple Watch or show on iPhone,
Official reference: [Apple Watch Programming Guide - Notification Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1)

may be helped

Comment: That's good. but "at appropriate times" what does it mean?. Is there any set of use cases.

Comment: when you send then display in watch.somtime late..becz server solw or any other problem