# How to get Push Notifications of iPhone App on Apple Watch using cordova without apple watch App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an iPhone Mobile App using Cordova, For that I have integrated push notification plugin, I am receiving successfully push notification in my iOS devices.
I want to show same notification with Apple Watch. 
So my question is How does the Apple watch handle notifications from apps that don't have a apple watch app ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple handle notifications on Apple Watch in the same way as on iPhone. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419041/how-to-display-push-notification-in-apple-watch)